# Is it possible to validate that one of 2 parameters are present using class-validator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, nestjs, class-validator

Using class-validator along with NestJS I want to validate that a user provides either `propertyA` or a `propertyB` but they don't need to provide both.

Currently, I'm doing something like:

```js
export class TestDto {
  @ValidateIf(obj => !obj.propertyB)
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  propertyA

  @ValidateIf(obj => !obj.propertyA)
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  propertyB
}
```

If they provide none of the parameters there will be multiple errors saying that `propertyA` and `propertyB` are required and should be strings etc.

In the case that they provide neither property, I would want only a single error saying something like: "You must provide propertyA or propertyB."

Can this be accomplished using NestJS/class-validator?

Comment: Hello. Your solution has another bottleneck too. Actually I opened a feat request in the class-validator and I provide there a proposal for our problem too. You can vote me up there too: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/1581

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know whether this functionality exists in class-validator or not but you can simply achieve this scenario using **Pipes**

Just create a **custom pipe** and then define the logic over there

```
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class CustomValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: TestDto , metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if(value.porpertyA && value.porpertyB) throw new HttpException("You must provide propertyA or propertyB" , 400)
    else return value;
  }
}
```

After That, you can use that Pipe over the controller

```
  @Post()
  create(@Body( new CustomValidationPipe()) testDto: TestDto) {
    return "create Resource"
  }
```

You can also use it in combination with a builtIn Validation Pipe just like this. In this case, your class validator logic will be executed first and then your custom pipe will execute

```
  @Post()
  create(@Body(ValidationPipe ,  new CustomValidationPipe()) testDto: TestDto) {
    return "create Resource"
  }
```

Hope This Helps

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding a new custom decorator to your class validator.

First, you must add a custom validation class (read [document](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-classes)) and then define a custom decorator for that (read [document](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-decorators)).

You can see how to do that in this [article](https://dev.to/avantar/custom-validation-with-database-in-nestjs-gao).

Comment: Link-only answers are usually deleted, you should add an example of code in your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create custom Property Decorators, this is the solution I came up with for one of my projects.

Simply set the fields to optional and then add an additional field that will do the check

```
export class TestDto {
    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    a?: string;

    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    b?: string;

    // if nothing has been provided
    @ValidateIf(o => !o.a && !o.b)
    @IsDefined({message: 'At least one of a or b must be provided'})
    protected readonly atLeastOne: undefined;

    // if both have been provided
    @ValidateIf(o => o.a && o.b)
    @IsDefined({message: 'Only one of a or b may be provided'})
    protected readonly checkOnlyOne: undefined;

    // the 2 checks above combined
    @ValidateIf(o => (!o.a && !o.b) || (o.a && o.b))
    @IsDefined({message: 'Provide either a or b, and only one of them'})
    protected readonly combinedCheck: undefined;
}
```

ps. you wont need to use all these checks at the same time :)